# Implementing non member functions

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment and have hit a wall on a particular area.  I can't figure out how I am supposed to implement the non member functions from the header into the .cpp file.  Here is the header:

```
class complx
{
    double real, imag;
public:
    complx( double real = 0., double imag = 0.); // constructor
    complx operator+(complx);       // operator+()

    complx operator+(double);       // operator+()with double
    complx operator- (complx);       // operator-()
    complx operator* (complx);       // operator*()

    bool operator== (complx);   // operator==()


    //Sets private data members.
    void Set(double new_real, double new_imaginary) {
        real = new_real;
        imag = new_imaginary;
    }

    //Returns the real part of the complex number.
    double Real() {
        return real;
    }

    //Returns the imaginary part of the complex number.
    double Imaginary() {
        return imag;
    }
};

ostream &operator << ( ostream &out_file, complx number );

extern istream &operator >> ( istream &in_file, complx &number );

extern ifstream &operator >> ( ifstream &in_file, complx &number );

complx &operator + (double, complx);
complx &operator - (double, complx);
complx &operator * (double, complx);
}
```

I have most of the member functions figured out, but it's the three at the bottom of the header that are giving me fits.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

p.s. sorry for the formatting, it's not copying over very well.

Comment: For one thing, the signatures are WRONG.  There's no non-temporary object to return a reference to.  Return by value instead.

Comment: Find and replace your tabs with 4 spaces, then paste, select and press the "format as code" button (`{}` icon).

Comment: I honestly don't believe you can implement any of the six operators at the bottom of your header.  Yes, you can overload an operator for a class.  No, I don't believe you can overload an operator *without* a class...  If that's even what you're actually trying to do...

Comment: why do you have double and complx? shouldn't it be:             complx  operator+ (const complx& c) const
complx  operator- (const complx& c) const
complx  operator* (const complx& c) const

Comment: @pualsm4 You can :)  Actually that is the preferred way of providing operators for a class: define a basic operation (e.g. `std::ostream::operator<<(char)` and create operators for your types using that primitive operator (e.g. `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::string)`)

Comment: I'm not sure why there is both double and complx.  Thats the unaltered header that was given to us for the assignment.

Comment: You need double and complex in the free functions for when you're saying
Complx c(1.0, 2.0);
Complx d = 0.5 + c;
rather than
Complx e = c + 0.5;
(the member operator+ handles when Complx is on the left-hand side, but when it's on the right, it has to use a free function)

BTW, sorry about the formatting :)

Comment: @Attila - Just another reason why C++ is the worst language of all time; a software disaster of Biblical proportions :)

Comment: @paulsm4 Tastes vary :)  If you write proper code in C++, it's not that bad (I actually prefer the way of the RAII to java, for example).  Of course you _can_ write horrible code in C++, but that's true for any language -- maybe it's easier to do so in C++ :)

Answer (score 0):

In your .ccp file goes:

```
ostream &operator << ( ostream &out_file, complx number )
{
  out_file << number.Real() << "," << number.Imaginary();
  return out_file;
}
```

Similarly for the others.

The trick is to decompose the complex number into its elements (Real and Imaginary) and perform the required operations on those (and create a new complex object for the return value of `+`, `-`, `*`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I think I get it now with the stream &operator portion.  I'm still not quite certain what you mean by create a new complex object for the return value of the operators?

Comment: the return type of `operator+` is `complx`, so you will have to create the complex object that you return from the operator.  This returned object will have the sum of the double and the input parameter's Real value and the same Imaginary value as the input parameter's.  (This is assuming that the double has to be added to the real part, not to the imaginary or both).  Similarly for the other operators.

Comment: Alright I have it figured out.  Thanks again for all your help.